# Reading file to a string of arrays

Tags: c, string, file

I was wondering how to properly read a file and place each line in a string of arrays in C.

I have a file with the following written on it

```
one
two
three
four
```

I tried writing something like this:

```
int read_file(FILE *fp){
   char readLine[MAX_LEN];
   char *myarray[20];
   int counter =0;
   int i =0;
   while(fgets(readLine,MAX_LEN,fp) != NULL){
      myarray[counter] = readLine;
      counter++;
   }

   /*printing the array*/
   while(i<counter){
      printf("%d  %s",i,myarray[i]);
      i++;
   }
}
```

and the main would be something like

```
int main(){
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("my.txt","r");
   if(fp == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"File does not exist");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   read_file(fp);
}
```

however, when printing I get:

```
four
four
four
four
```

even when I print using `printf("%s",myarr[2])` , I still get `four`

Anyone knows what the problem may be?

Comment: Think very carefully about what this is actually doing:`myarray[counter] = readLine;` Hint: this *isn't* Java. And in the future. *"I tried writing something like this"*. Please post the *real* code that is causing the *real* problem. Analyzing code that is not the actual problematic code is often a *monumental* time waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to make a copy of the line (by way of `strdup()`) as you are overwriting the buffer used to accept the input:

```
int read_file(FILE *fp){
   char readLine[MAX_LEN];
   char *myarray[20];     // Note char pointer!
   int i, counter = 0;
   while (counter < 20 && fgets(readLine,MAX_LEN,fp) != NULL) {    // Note limit!
      myarray[counter] = strdup(readLine);
      counter++;
   }

   /*printing the array*/
   for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
      printf("%d  %s",i,myarray[i]);

   /* free the lines */
   for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        free(myarray[i]);   
}
```

Comment: You can free the line immediately after printing it, you don't even need two loops (albeit I doubt the optimizer doesn't do some loop fusion on them).

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course, but I have a sneaking suspicion the OP will start passing this array around his program soonish...

Comment: @teojanfoe Sure :) (However, WhozCraig's "think carefully" comment *still* applies to him :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
myarray[counter] = readLine;
```

is the problem. You are overriding the read line pointer values each time.

use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy the buffer content instead.

In addition as commented: you are not declaring array of strings, merely one string.

Change it to:

```
char myarray[4][20];
```

Of course, 4 is an example. Change it to any number of lines or use dynamic allocation.

Comment: That won't help.  `myarray[counter]` is a single `char` and `readLine` is an array.